# How to create a script that returns only the mobile devices on a network using NMAP

Tags: nmap

I would like to create a script using NMAP on Mac that 1) scans the entire LAN, and 2)  Returns the number of mobile devices.

Comment: Please tell us what research you have done for the problem so that we can help fill-in the gaps.

Answer (score 1):

Point 1 is fairly easy :
$ nmap -n -T4 -PN -sV -sS -sU **192.168.1.0/24** --exclude **my_ip**

You have to specify your own network address and mask obviously.

Point 2 :
If by mobile devices, you mean phones and tablets, then I think you can listen for some specific port. (e.g 62078/tcp open iphone-sync). I would not rely on OS Detection (-A, -O) as iOS and OS X is often mixed up with nmap probes. I do not know the ports for Android devices / Windows phones, so feel free to google it.

A majority of phones are quite locked up, and do not listen for any connection / or return no fingerprint. So I would not rely purely on nmap for this script. You can listen the traffic with Wireshark, figured what phone generate which traffic (iOS for instance generate some Bonjour communication) and then script this using bash and tshark.
Finally if you can sniff the traffic (NIDS would be the best, do not use arp cache poisoning), you can analyse some network traffic such as the User-Agent(HTTP header).